# Clojure 1.2.1/1.3/1.4 'proxy generated in Grails 2.0.0 runtime fails. 1.2.0 is fine

Tags: grails, groovy, clojure, proxy

I'm working on extending the [Grails Clojure plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/clojure) in [Grails 2.0.0](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/introduction.html) (and 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT) and I wanted to update it to [Clojure 1.3.0](http://clojure.org/downloads) and add [clojure.tools.logging](https://github.com/clojure/tools.logging).

Clojure throws an exception during compilation of a 
*proxy* of a `ByteArrayOutputStream` in `clojure.tools.logging`'s log-stream function:

`ClassCastException: clojure.asm.Type cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn`

( https://gist.github.com/a6ae681c37091a3d2379 )

I went and removed `clojure.tools.logging` and wrote a stripped down *proxy* of `Object`:

`(proxy [java.lang.Object] [] (toString [] "proxy's toString"))`

and it also threw that same `ClassCastException` and message.

I tried to print a *macroexpand-1* of the *proxy* and got the same thing.

I reverted to Clojure 1.2.0 and *proxy* worked fine again.

I tried a number of incarnations of 1.4.0 and they exhibit the same behavior as 1.3.0. 
1.2.1 also throws some sort of exception but I'm trying to hit 1.3.0 so I didn't spend much time with that.

The stack trace points to the 'gen-method function defined in one of the *let* forms of `generate-proxy` in `core_proxy.clj`.

I added a small smattering of `println`'s around there to see if I could catch what was happening. Maybe this next statement will betray a huge misunderstanding of the reader on my part but simply adding those `println`s changed the compile time behavior in a way I totally didn't expect. The exception location and exception type completely changed, even though all the Clojure tests in `mvn package` continue to pass.

For instance, just adding a single `println` to gen-method right before it starts generating bytecode caused Clojure to throw

`ClassCastException: clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap cannot be cast to java.lang.Class`

( https://gist.github.com/5a7a40929a6c4a104bd5 )

I've seen various other errors depending on where I put the `println`(s) but this is the most prevalent.

Obviously some aspect of Grails and Clojure are not meshing correctly here, but I am not seeing the connection. At first I suspected ASM incompatibility but since Clojure has its own ASM namespace, I can't see that being the issue. But maybe I'm wrong, I've been staring at `clojure.lang.Compiler`, *proxy* and *generate-proxy* for days now trying to get this to work and I've pretty much stopped making forward progress because I've run out of steam :(

I apologize for the lack of links. You can copy and paste from below:

Grails Clojure - [github.com/grails-plugins/grails-clojure](http://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-clojure)

Clojure Tools Logging - [github.com/clojure/tools.logging/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/tools/logging.clj](http://github.com/clojure/tools.logging/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/tools/logging.clj) line 133 is the 'proxy

Comment: I've done some more testing and I'm all but convinced it's something in Grails 2.0 that's wrecking something Clojure 1.3 relies on. I tested the simplest code sample I can conceive in Grails 1.3.7, Groovy 1.8.4 (which is what Grails 2.0 uses) and Groovy 1.8.5 (the latest) and those all work.

Comment: Could this be a ClassLoader issue?

Answer (score 4):

I found an Issue called `CLJ-944` on [clojure.org](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-944). There you can find a fix for `ClassCastException: clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap cannot be cast to java.lang.Class` issue

The problem is:

> that the compiler injects an incorrect cast to
>   clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap. In this case it should probably be
>   cast to a clojure.lang.Associative, the highest common interface
>   having the .containsKey method.

Patch 1 - [0001-Fix-for-CLJ-944.patch](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/secure/attachment/11644/0001-Fix-for-CLJ-944.patch)

Patch 2 - [0002-Fix-for-CLJ-944.patch](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/secure/attachment/11655/0002-Fix-for-CLJ-944.patch)

I hope it helps.